# can be configure Composer to use http instead git clone git@

Tags: git, composer-php, git-clone

We are using some private repositories with satis, and first try to download the code with git clone @git, and after two try it download it with git clone http://....

There is any way to configure composer to use with the private repositories git clone http by default?

Thanks.

Oskar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try, for testing:

```
git config --global url."https://github.com/".insteadOf git@github.com:
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```

That would ensure any system (like Composer) using git clone would use HTTPS URL instead of SSH ones.

Comment: Thanks VonC. I'm going to try it.

Comment: @OskarCalvo Note that you need to adapt the http URL to your private server: I was just giving an example using GitHub.